# Change text color of H1 using setTimeout function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have three  headings in my html. On page load I want to change the color of these headings one by one and it should start again with the first one after the last heading. I have tried setTimeout function of JS but cant get the result which I want.

It should work like this:

- "Text 1" – Green color for 10 seconds
- "Text 2" – Green color for 15 Seconds
- "Text 3" – Green color for 18 seconds

After "Text 3", it should again start with "Text 1"

Below is my code.

```html
<body onload="startAuto()">
    <h1 id="first">Text 1</h1>
    <h1 id="second">Text 2</h1>
    <h1 id="third">Text 3</h1>
</body>
```

I have used the following JavaScript its working first time but when it reaches to Text 3 it doesn't go back to Text 1.

```js
function startAuto() {
  function first() {
    document.getElementById('first').style.color = "#32A067";
  }

  function second() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('first').style.color = "#333";
      document.getElementById('second').style.color = "#32A067";
    }, 13000);
  }

  second();

  function third() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('first').style.color = "#333";
      document.getElementById('second').style.color = "#333";
      document.getElementById('third').style.color = "#32A067";
    }, 26000);
  }

  third();
}
```

Comment: if you need any more explanation about my answer, don't hesitate

Comment: Check out my solution, Im sure, you will like it ;)

Comment: thanks all. I have also posted my own version of solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all these answers but I have found the easiest and cleanest solution myself. Just settimeout function in the previous one, in a circular fashion. Its more nicer and clear. Below is the code snippet.

```
<body>
    <h1 id="first">Text 1</h1>
    <h1 id="second">Text 2</h1>
    <h1 id="third">Text 3</h1>
</body>


<script>
first();

function first()
{

document.getElementById('third').style.color="#333";

document.getElementById('first').style.color="#32A067";

setTimeout(second,10000);

}


function second()
{

document.getElementById('first').style.color="#333";
document.getElementById('second').style.color="#32A067";

setTimeout(third,15000);

}



function third()
{

document.getElementById('second').style.color="#333";
document.getElementById('first').style.color="#32A067";

setTimeout(first,18000);


}
</script>
```

Comment: good, but things will be tiring when you want to add another header

Comment: @Quantumass yea you are right. But since I have these only 3 main headings thats why I am going with this approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a circular array and timeout to sleep and recall the function

`listElements` contains all the elements you want to highlight and their highlight time

`startAutoIndex` will be increment each time the function is called so it will start with element id first

```js
var startAutoIndex = 0

function startAuto() {

    let listElements = [
        {id: "first", timer: 10000}, 
        {id: "second", timer: 13000}, 
        {id: "third", timer: 26000}
    ]

    function colorHeader(currentIndex) {
        for (let index = 0; index < listElements.length; index++) {
            const element = listElements[index]
            if (currentIndex != index)
                document.getElementById(element.id).style.color = '#333'
            else {
                document.getElementById(element.id).style.color = '#32A067'
            }
        }
    }

    let currentIndex =
        ((startAutoIndex % listElements.length) + listElements.length) %
        listElements.length

    colorHeader(currentIndex)

    setTimeout(startAuto, listElements[currentIndex].timer)

    startAutoIndex = currentIndex + 1

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I have found my own solution and for me thats more clear. Can you please have a look on that below is my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the main timer inside an interval, and each highlight event as a separate timeout.

I would also add a class to the elements you want to query for, or just select all `h1` elements.

You could also provided a fixed timeout, and it will calculate the timeouts between elements for you.

```js
window.startAuto = () => {
  start({
    selector : '.highlighter',
    timeouts : [ 1000, 2000, 1000 ], // or, for a fixed timout: 1000
    callback : (el, index, activeIndex) => {
      el.classList.toggle('active', index === activeIndex);
    }
  });
};

const defaultOptions = {
  selector : '',
  timeouts : [],
  initialDelay : 0
};

const start = (options) => {
  let opts = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
  opts.elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(opts.selector));
  let interval = 0;
  if (!Array.isArray(opts.timeouts)) {
    opts.timeouts = fillArray(opts.timeouts, opts.elements.length);
  }
  interval = opts.timeouts.reduce((t, x) => t + x, 0);
  opts.timeouts = normalizeTimeouts(opts.timeouts);
  setTimeout(() => {
    update(opts);
    setInterval(update, interval, opts);
  }, opts.initialDelay);
};

const normalizeTimeouts = (timeouts) => {
  return timeouts.reduce((results, timeout, index, all) => {
    return results.concat(timeout + all.slice(0, index).reduce((t, x) => t + x, 0));
  }, [0]);
};

const update = (opts) => {
  opts.timeouts.slice(0, opts.timeouts.length -1).forEach((timeout, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      opts.elements.forEach((element, i) => {
        return opts.callback.call(element, element, i, index);
      });
    }, timeout);
  })
};

const fillArray = (value, count) => new Array(count).fill(value);
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startAuto()">
  <h1 class="highlighter" id="first">Text 1</h1>
  <h1 class="highlighter" id="second">Text 2</h1>
  <h1 class="highlighter" id="third">Text 3</h1>
</body>
```

---

Here is a super-dynamic; reusable class.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => main());

const main = () => {
  let looper = new Looper({
    selector : '.highlighter',
    timeouts : [ 1000, 2000, 1000 ], // or, for a fixed timout: 1000
    callback : (el, index, activeIndex) => {
      el.classList.toggle('active', index === activeIndex);
    },
    initialDelay : 1000,
    autoStart : true
  })
  
  document.querySelector('#stop-btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    looper.stop();
  });
  
  document.querySelector('#restart-btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    looper.stop();
    looper.start();
  });
}

class Looper {
  constructor(options) {
    let opts = Object.assign({}, Looper.defaultOptions, options);
    this.elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(opts.selector));
    if (!Array.isArray(opts.timeouts)) {
      opts.timeouts = this.__fillArray(opts.timeouts, this.elements.length);
    }
    this.interval = opts.timeouts.reduce((t, x) => t + x, 0);
    this.timeouts = this.__normalizeTimeouts(opts.timeouts);
    this.initialDelay = opts.initialDelay;
    this.autoStart = opts.autoStart;
    this.callback = opts.callback;
    this.__startupId = null;
    this.__processId = null;
    this.__subprocessIds = this.__fillArray(null, this.elements.length);
    
    if (this.autoStart === true) this.start();
  }
  
  start() {
    if (this.callback == null) {
      throw new Error('callback function is undefined');
    }
    if (this.__processId == null) {
      this.__startupId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.__update();
        this.__processId = setInterval(() => {
          this.__update();
        }, this.interval);
      }, this.initialDelay);
    }
  }

  stop() {
    this.__subprocessIds.forEach((id, index) => {
      if (id != null) {
        clearTimeout(id);
        this.__subprocessIds[index] = null;
      }
    });
    if (this.__processId != null) {
      clearInterval(this.__processId);
      this.__processId = null;
    }
    if (this.__startupId != null) {
      clearTimeout(this.__startupId);
      this.__startupId = null;
    }
  }

  __update() {
    let self = this;
    self.timeouts.slice(0, this.timeouts.length -1).forEach((timeout, index) => {
      self.__subprocessIds[index] = setTimeout(() => {
        self.elements.forEach((element, i) => {
          return self.callback.call(element, element, i, index);
        });
      }, timeout);
    })
  }

  __normalizeTimeouts(timeouts) {
    return timeouts.reduce((results, timeout, index, all) => {
      return results.concat(timeout + all.slice(0, index).reduce((t, x) => t + x, 0));
    }, [0]);
  }

  __fillArray(value, count) {
    return new Array(count).fill(value);
  }
}

Looper.defaultOptions = {
  selector : '',
  timeouts : [],
  initialDelay : 0,
  autoStart : false
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 class="highlighter" id="first">Text 1</h2>
  <h2 class="highlighter" id="second">Text 2</h2>
  <h2 class="highlighter" id="third">Text 3</h2>
</div>

<button id="stop-btn">Stop</button>
<button id="restart-btn">Restart</button>
```

Comment: @Polywhirl Thanks for your answer, although I have found my own solution and for me thats Mclear. Can you please have a look on my answer any suggestion would be helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout together with promises to achive result you want. Check out my snippet:

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');
  var second = document.getElementById('second');
  var third = document.getElementById('third');



 const promiseTimeout = (delay, element, newColor) =>
   {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
       
        element.style.color = newColor;
        resolve() // when this fires, .then gets called
        
      }, delay)
    });
   }

 function start(){

  first.style.color = "green";

  promiseTimeout(10000, first, "#333")
  .then(() => {
   return second.style.color = "green";
  })
  .then(() => {
   return promiseTimeout(15000, second, "#333")
  })
  .then(() => {
   third.style.color = "green";
   return promiseTimeout(18000, third, "#333")
  })
  .then(() => start());
 }

 start();
```

```html
<h1 id="first">Text 1</h1>

<h1 id="second">Text 2</h1>

<h1 id="third">Text 3</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I have found my own solution and for me thats more clear. Can you please have a look on that below is my answer.  Thanks